# How would you format this array?

Tags: php

So I have an array. It looks like this, yes it is proxies.

```
Array ( [0] => 
[29] => 1.164.146.151:80
[30] => 1.174.251.189:80
[31] => 1.175.136.1:3128
[32] => 1.175.142.176:3128
[33] => 1.179.176.37:8080
[34] => 1.179.183.109:8080
[35] => 1.179.183.89:8080
[36] => 1.179.185.249:8080
[37] => 1.179.189.217:8080
[38] => 1.179.198.17:8080
[39] => 1.194.129.104:808
[40] => 1.195.7.117:53281
[41] => 1.195.9.60:808
[42] => 1.197.200.131:808
[43] => 1.197.58.69:808
)
```

How would I make it so it formats like this. I need this because since curl only takes in proxies and port in different parameters. I'm hoping someone can answer this question for me. I tried to also use explode and it didn't work because it's supposed to be a string and not an array.

```
Array ( [0] =>
[29] => 1.164.146.151
[30] => 80
)
```

Comment: Try using `explode` in a foreach and make an array, when you have a prototype and have difficulties please come back. Also try to validate the IP (just in case) with `filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)`

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your array and split the strings using `explode()`

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $element)
{
    $newArray[] = explode(':', $element);
}
```

`$array` is your raw array and `$newArray` the prepared one

Example: https://eval.in/820983

Comment: But how would you access an array like that since it's 2 => 
  array (
    0 => '1.175.136.1',
    1 => '3128',
  ),
which is weird.

Comment: You can do your curl call inside the foreach loop and index `0` is the IP and index `1` the port -> `$element[0]` and `$element[1]`

Comment: What happens if I want to echo out the value except doing the curl call. Since I want it to be separate to be more organized so the other file is just grabbing the contents of this file. I also can't even echo this out.

Comment: `echo $element[0]` will echo the IP, and `echo $element[1]` will echo the port. (inside the foreach-loop)